# How to user path Twig function to call another bundle and routing.yml in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to call register from my login screen for the user. I have two separate bundles for this: LoginBundle and RegisterBundle. I'd appreciate if someone can raise some points for this, thank you in advance.

My login form would be something like this:

```
{% block body %}

<h1 class="title">Login</h1>
<p>
    Choose between two default users: <em>user/userpass</em> <small>(ROLE_USER)</small> or <em>admin/adminpass</em> <small>(ROLE_ADMIN)</small>
</p>

<div class="error"></div>

<div class="wrapper">
<form action="{{ path('login_process') }}" method="post" id="login" class="form-signin">       
  <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email Address" required="" autofocus="" />
  <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"  class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>      
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
  <a href="{{ path('register') }}" targer='_blank'>Register</a>   
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The way I overcome the issue was to "/register" path and Symfony will automatically find the route for you.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by your solution description. Can you provide an example?